# Node JS with CouchDB for lots o' parsing

Tags: node.js, couchdb

My team and I are playing around with NodeJS (with jsdom/jQuery) and parsing a lot of HTML documents stored in CouchDB. NodeJS is single threaded so having 8 cores in a serve does not help us at all initially, this is where I was wondering how to best create child processes (workers perhaps?) to process the individual file as it's pulled out from CouchDB?

Here is my thought process:

1. Main NodeJS script loops through CouchDB view getting the HTML files from documents every X minutes
2. Spawn a process to parse (jsdom/jQuery) and store the results from each HTML file

We aren't running a webserver at all to handle any of this (all command line) so I am unsure of how to handle this outside of a generic "set up CRON to just run each parsing job seperately". It seems that workers are generally used to process requests coming in from a webserver.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [`cluster`](http://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/cluster.html)

```
var cluster = require("cluster");
var numCPUs = require('os').cpus().length;
var htmlDocs = [...];

if (cluster.isMaster) {
  // Fork workers.
  for (var i = 0; i < numCPUs; i++) {
    cluster.fork();
  }

  cluster.on('death', function(worker) {
    console.log('worker ' + worker.pid + ' died');
  });
} else {
  for (var i = process.env.NODE_WORKER_ID; i < htmlDocs.length; i+=numCPUs) {
    couch.doWork(htmlDocs[i]);
  }
}
```

This is a classic case of doing work on members in an array and then splitting that work out over multiple processes by having each process do a subset of the array.

Note how we increment i by number of processes. This means worker 1 does 1st, 5th, 9th, etc, worker 2 does 2nd, 6th, 10th, etc.

Comment: Thanks! I think this is what we are going to use.